# JavaScript: Finding the array-defined range into which a float value falls

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a user-generated JavaScript object that will be formatted as follows:

```js
a = {
  "A": [1.20, 1.75],
  "B": [1.80, 2.25],
  "C": [2.35, 3.15],
  "1": [3.40, 3.95],
  "2": [3.97, 4.15],
  "3": [4.30, 5.15]
}
```

Given a float `x`, I want to identify between which two values in the same array—if any—`x` is. I also want to be able to tell if `x` is outside of the range of values referenced in *all* of the arrays or if it is in between two sets of values. That is, I want a function `f(a, x)` such that:

- `f(a, 4.01)` returns `"2"`
- `f(a, 4.20)` returns `["2", "3"]` (as `4.20` is between the ranges specified in `"2"` and `"3"`)
- `f(a, 1.05)` returns `"less"` (as `1.05` is less than the smallest value mentioned in the arrays, `1.20`)
- `f(a, 5.20)` returns `"greater"` (as `5.20` is greater than the largest value referenced in the arrays, `5.15`)

I know how to hard-code this for *one* particular object (by using a very long series of `if` and `else if` statements), and I suppose I could concatenate all of the arrays into one long array and then check between which pair of values `x` fell (or find another very tedious solution).

My question is: **Is there a simple way to carry out this task?** For example, a library, built-in function, etc.

I am using server-side Node.js, so if you know of a package available on NPM, that would work.

Because the object will be user-generated, bonus points if you have a way to throw errors if there are formatting issues (e.g., overlapping ranges).

---

*P.S. I don't know if I explained this clearly. If you don't understand, please leave a comment so that I can clarify.*

Comment: If you know how to do it for one value, just loop that code.

Comment: What do you want to return when the object is `{A: [1,2], B: [4,5]}` and the value is `3`? It's neither less nor greater than all ranges.

Comment: @Bergi It would be in between `A` and `B`, so it should return `["A", "B"]`. And I meant that I know how to hard-code it as a function for one *pre-determined* value of `a`. The function would have to be rewritten if the value of `a` changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create boundaries from the `Object.values` and locate the boundaries of the given value. Based on the `lower` and `upper` boundary, you can check if the `Object.entries` `includes` it.

```js
const calc = (data, val) => {
  const boundaries = Object.values(data).flat(1).sort((a, b) => a - b);

  if (val < Math.min(...boundaries)) return "less"; // if < min
  if (val > Math.max(...boundaries)) return "greater"; // if > max

  const entries = Object.entries(data); // get object entries

  // if value is a boundary
  if (boundaries.includes(val))
    return entries.map(([k, v]) => v.includes(val) ? k : null).filter(x => x);

  const allLower = boundaries.filter((b) => val > b);
  const lower = boundaries[allLower.length - 1]; // get lower
  const upper = boundaries[boundaries.indexOf(lower) + 1]; // get upper

  return entries.map(([k, v]) => {
    return v.includes(lower) || v.includes(upper) ? k : null
  }).filter(x => x);
}

const a = { 
  "A": [1.20, 1.75], "B": [1.80, 2.25], "C": [2.35, 3.15],
  "1": [3.40, 3.95], "2": [3.97, 4.15], "3": [4.30, 5.15]
}

console.log(calc(a, 4.01)); // 2
console.log(calc(a, 4.20)); // 2, 3
console.log(calc(a, 1.05)); // less
console.log(calc(a, 5.20)); // greater
```

Comment: Does anybody know of a library that has this functionality?

Comment: @BenZ. I don't, but I think you could accomplish similar things with lodash

Comment: Do you know what Lodash function would be similar?

Comment: @BenZ. I haven't used it enough to tell you, but you could check it out in the docs https://lodash.com/docs/